# Visual Studio Intellisense doesn't work well when I try it in an empty project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I use visual studio 2017 and It's IntelliSense tool work well unless when I use it in an empty project. When I build an empty project popup suggestion of intellisense drops down but not showing methos and properties of relevant classes. What Should I do? Do I need to add any .dll to my empty project?

Comment: If you have no references to your dll files, off course visual studio wont know about whats inside them for intellisense. You have to references them and references it by a using statement.

Comment: What are "relevant classes"? Do you mean standard C# classes like `Console`? Or do you another *(your custom)* classes? Write example class and expected behaviour. What do you mean by "not showing methods and properties"? When you press `.` (dot) after variable/class name no methods are displayed? Or methods are displayed, but no description for methods/properties are displayed? I had the same problem in Visual Studio *(I think it was 2013)* when I tried to create a .NET 2.0 project and did not have installed previous version of Visual Studio 2008. I saw this first time after PC reinstall.

Comment: Sometimes the intellisense need some time to load all the definitions. Even for an empty project.

Comment: I add System .dll and System.Drawing .dll and iTextSharp .dll in my Empty Project but non of all namespaces does not show it's classes and methods in intellisense? P.S. I add these namespaces to my project by using keyword

Comment: @vahidmajedi make a console app and use the same project id and projecttype from.csproj file and match it your .csproj and see if this make it work

Comment: @vahidmajedi, hi, what's your project type and could you please share a screenshot after you build this empty project? It seems we can create a blank solution in VS and there is no empty project type, please share more detail information and that will help us analysis this issue, thanks.